# NuGet confusion - can you win the game

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

Env: Powershell 7 on Macos

I am trying to install [grpc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/aspnet/aspnetcore.docs/create-grpc-client/) packages:

```
install-Package Grpc.Net.Client
```

It hangs "forever", so I try to install

```
Install-Package Google.Protobuf
```

Then is comes up with:

```
Install-Package: Unable to find dependent package(s) (System.Reflection)
```

Ok, then I try to install:

```
Install-Package System.Reflection
```

Then it comes up with:

```
WARNING: 'System.Reflection' matched package 'System.Reflection/4.3.0' from provider: 'NuGet', source 'System.Reflection'.
WARNING: 'System.Reflection' matched package 'System.Reflection/4.1.0' from provider: 'NuGet', source 'nuget.org'.
Install-Package: Unable to install, multiple packages matched 'System.Reflection'. Please specify a single -Source.
```

Then I try:

```
 Install-Package System.Reflection -Source nuget.org
```

Then it comes up with:

```
The package(s) come(s) from a package source that is not marked as trusted.
Are you sure you want to install software from 'nuget.org'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"):
```

Then I try:

```
Register-PackageSource -Name System.Reflection -Provider Nuget
```

Then I get:

```
Register-PackageSource: Package Source 'System.Reflection' exists.
```

Then I try....:

```
Well, I really dont know how this packagemanager can help me?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: use `dotnet add package Grpc.Net.Client`, or whatever NuGet functionality exists in Visual Studio for Mac, if you use that.

longer version: [NuGet's docs for its `Install-Package` powershell cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-install-package) says:

> This topic describes the command within the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio on Windows. For the generic PowerShell Install-Package command, see the PowerShell PackageManagement reference.

[Powershell's docs on their `Install-Package` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/Install-Package?view=powershell-6) doesn't define, or have a link, to what they consider a "software package", however, my understanding is that powershell packages add new Powershell commands to Powershell.

So, Powershell's `Install-Package` is not for installing NuGet packages into .NET projects, but powershell modules can be distributed as NuGet packages. NuGet's `Install-Package` is only available in Visual Studio on Windows. It's a really unfortunate name clash that can't be fixed without breaking a lot of people, so frankly I can't imagine it ever being changed.

The GRPC sample that you linked to perhaps doesn't make it clear enough that the powershell commands only work in Visual Studio for Windows. The only reference to powershell that I could see was a small title above the code block saying that the contents of the code block is powershell, but the instructions about the code block explicitly says to select menus that I believe only exist in Visual Studio for Windows.

Many Microsoft docs pages have a comments section at the bottom, but unfortunately the sample you linked doesn't, so I'll create an issue on your behalf asking the docs maintainers to improve it.

As mentioned in the tl;dr sentence at the top, if your project is an SDK style project, you can use the dotnet CLI to add a package to your project: `dotnet add package <package_id>`.

Comment: Thanks, "dotnet add package" might be the way for me to go

Comment: @ChrisG. I think I found the same tutorial on another URL, this time with instructions specific for VSCode and Visual Studio for Mac users: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Just to add to this. There is a NuGet Package Manager Console available for Visual Studio for Mac - however it is a separate extension you need to install - http://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions/ - or you can just use Visual Studio for Mac's built-in NuGet support.  However if you are not using Visual Studio for Mac then `dotnet add package` or `nuget install` will be your best bet.